# Codename One center component in container

Tags: layout, codenameone

I have an app that uses a container as drop target.

When a label is released over the container, I would like the label to be automatically centered inside the container.

From what I have tried, setting a TableLayout with constraints for the container does not work and BoxLayout needs constraints defined before adding the component.

Is there any method to center the content of a container directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove and re-add the component in the table layout but that can be "flaky" as it might go to the next row/column unless those are explicitly stated.

Two good approaches to center a component:

```
Container centered = BorderLayout.centerAbsolute(myCmp);
```

Or

```
Container centered = FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(myCmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
Container centered = FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle();
```

with no arguments works in case you use the container as a drop target and don't know from the start what component will be released over it (my case).

```
Container centered = BorderLayout.centerAbsolute(myCmp);
```

requires you to define a component (myCmp).